# How to abort unchecking item at checkedlistbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a method:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Columns)
            {
                geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.Items.Add(column.HeaderText, column.Visible);
                geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.ItemCheck += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                    if (geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.SelectedItem != "Show")
                    {
                        if (geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.SelectedItem != null)
                        {
                            var selectedItem = geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.SelectedItem.ToString();

                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn column2 in dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Columns)
                            {
                                if (column2.HeaderText == selectedItem.ToString())
                                {
                                    column2.Visible = ee.NewValue == CheckState.Checked;
                                }
                            }
                            int currentDisplayIndex = 0;

                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn in dgvGeoObjectsFirstView.Columns)
                            {
                                if (dataGridViewColumn.HeaderText == selectedItem)
                                {
                                    currentDisplayIndex = dataGridViewColumn.Index;
                                }
                            }



                            int futureDisplayIndex = geoObjectsColumnsCheckedListBoxFirstView.SelectedIndex;

                            PassColumnsInFirstView(futureDisplayIndex, currentDisplayIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
      //What can I do here to have item checked
                    }
                };
            }\
```

The problem is taht one column which header text "Show" shouldn't be uncheckable, so I want something like aborting unchecking for this item.

Maybe some event on checkedlistbox?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Make the column [read-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly.aspx) and then you needn't fiddle with preventing it from being changed.

Otherwise, subscribe to the `CellEndEdit` event and set `e.Cancel = true`.

Comment: Good idea, but not designer from my company :/ there must be as I wrote upon. But thx :)

Comment: @user278618: Certain constraints like not being able to edit certain things are kind of good to put in the question as information to others who aren't familiar with them..